# Java, How to set a variable through interface?

Tags: java, android, interface

In my project i defined an interface like this:

```
public interface SearchResultProgressListener {
    public void OnSearchCompleted(boolean value);
}
```

I've implemented this in class A (called SearchResultsActivity):

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends BaseActivity implements
         SearchResultProgressListener {

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private boolean timerStatus = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchresults);

        // Linking progressbar
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_fake);
        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 int temp = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                 switch(temp) {
                     case 9: temp = 1;   break;
                     case 8: temp = 2;   break;
                     case 7: temp = 3;   break;
                     case 6: temp = 4;   break;
                     case 5: temp = 5;   break;
                     case 4: temp = 6;   break;
                     case 3: temp = 7;   break;
                     case 2: temp = 8;   break;
                     case 1: temp = 9;   break;
                     case 0: temp = 10;  break;
                 }
                 Log.e("Hesam", "Status1: " + timerStatus);
                 if(!timerStatus)
                     mProgressBar.setProgress(temp);
                 else
                     mProgressBar.setProgress(10);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
          }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnSearchCompleted(boolean status) {
        this.timerStatus = status;
        Log.e("Hesam", "Status0: " + timerStatus);
    }
}
```

I have class B (called HotelsAsyncTaskFragment) that through this class I want to send Boolean to class A.

```
public class HotelsAsyncTaskFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private SearchResultProgressListener srpListener;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        srpListener = (SearchResultProgressListener) new SearchResultsActivity();
    }

    class HotelsSearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {...}

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {...}

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if(!isComplete()) {
                HotelsAsyncTaskFragment.this.srpListener.OnSearchCompleted(false);
                } else { 
            HotelsAsyncTaskFragment.this.srpListener.OnSearchCompleted(true);
                }
    }
    }
}
```

Now, I expect when I setting "timerStatus" in class A to "True", it's content changes but it doesn't. This is my Log:

```
02-13 16:41:58.716: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:13.566: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:14.566: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:14.611: E/Hesam(469): Status0: true
02-13 16:42:15.571: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:16.601: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:17.616: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:18.616: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:19.621: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:20.626: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
02-13 16:42:21.621: E/Hesam(469): Status1: false
```

As you can see, "timerStatus" is set to "true" in forth line but after that I have no idea why it is set to false!!!

any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is `localResults`?

Comment: @ baraky, in calss A, below switch();

Comment: @ Eng,I forgot to clear it. you consider a Boolean variable that can be true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the code for SearchResultsActivity() but it's clearly not the same as MainActivity(). The log entries you are seeing are coming from two different activities with two separate variables.

Comment: ops, it was my stupid mistake, sorry. it was my class A. I changed the code. I changed MainActivity with SearchResultsActivity.

Comment: Yes, but you are creating a new instance of the activity - you probably have two instances running.

Comment: You are great ;) I changed private boolean timerStatus = false; to private static boolean timerStatus = false; So, problem solved. Yes, as I said in other comment I was suspicious to new object that you verified it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have changed the code and it seems more clear now....

Did you try to debug the onPostExecute()?

If you see the log, it clearly says that it gets set to false multiple times but to true only once. So, debug your onPostExecute() method and mainly isComplete() function....

I hope the problem resides there.

Hope this will help you solving your problem.

Thanks...

Mr.777